# Is there any implicit-ish memoization in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, memoization

Is there any way to force GHC to thunk a particular computation for the lifetime of a particular value?

I could obviously place the value into a record, creating lazy record entries for the result of said computation, and create a maker function that builds the record and thunks the value into said entries.

I'd hate needing to pull the original value out from the record every time I wanted it though.  And Haskell has no adhocly polymorphic is-a relationships like C++ or Java.

Are there any trick for memoizing values across multiple unrelated invocations of a function with identical parameters?

I could vaguely imagine various tricks with forms of dependent types that'd effectively tell the compiler multiple usages were coming.  There aren't any dependent types in Haskell but maybe something around implicit parameters?  I suppose not, but I thought I'd ask.  A pragma perhaps?

---

Imagine I've a vector of `Necklace` data structures for which I need a resulting vector of rational numbers, stored as a common denominator and a vector of numerators.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Necklace = Necklace { ... }
necklace_length n = ...

denominator :: (necklaces :: V.Vector Necklace) => Int
denominator = V.foldl' lcm 30 $ V.map necklace_length ?necklaces

numerators :: (necklaces :: V.Vector Necklace) => V.Vector Int
numerators = V.map f ?necklaces
  where f x = ... denominator ...

kittytoy :: (necklaces :: V.Vector Necklace) => Meow -> ...
kittytoy = \meow -> ... numerators ...
```

A priori, I'd expect that, if I invoke `kittytoy` several million times, each with a different parameter `meow`, then GHC produces code that invokes `numerators` a million times, each with an identical implicit parameters `necklaces`.

It's nevertheless obvious that `numerators` only needs to be invoked once though, the first time `?necklaces` gets assigned, meaning GHC could potentially notice this optimization.

There should even be an explicit code refactoring approach using template haskell to explicitly pass the thunks by producing code like `?numerators = numerators` and adding `numerators :: V.Vector Int` to type constraints of functions that call it.

Comment: `kittytoy necklaces = let n = numerators necklaces in \meow -> stuff` should definitely memoize `n`. Not sure if it will also be this way as is as well.

Comment: Do you mean `let k = kittytoy in ...` replacing every call to `kittytoy` with `k`?  Yes, I'd agree that should memoize the implicit parameter `?necklaces`, but should I really need to do that?

Comment: Ahh, no I'm trying to memoize `numerators` *outside* the call to `kittytoy`, because `kittytoy` itself gets invoked several million times.  Yes, that's a valid point that `kittytoy` should be a lambda expression regardless, I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: It likely that `numerators` must be explicitly added to type constraints to achieve what I want, but maybe some template Haskell tricks exist for that.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably looking for pure memoisation, as implemented by [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators). Basically, it works by creating a (lazy, possibly infinite) tree structure with all the possible values of the function at each leaf, and then creating a new function that simply accesses the value at the relevant location. For instance, you can write a memoiser for functions `Bool -> a` like this:

```
memoBool :: (Bool -> a) -> (Bool -> a)
memoBool f =
    let fTrue = f True
        fFalse = f False
    in \b -> if b then fTrue else fFalse
```

In this case, the "tree structure" is rather bonsai, having only two leaves.

data-memocombinators packages this up in the `Memo a` type, defined as `forall r. (a -> r) -> (a -> r)`, with useful combinators like `pair :: Memo a -> Memo b -> Memo (a, b)` (read: if you can memoise functions of argument type `a`, and memoise functions of argument type `b`, you can memoise functions of argument type `(a, b)`).

This is pure, and pretty elegant, relying on the sharing implemented by basically all Haskell implementations (which is the same thing that makes your record idea work). Unfortunately, it's also not very fast, so for practical use you might want to use [uglymemo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uglymemo) instead, which uses a mutable `Map` behind the scenes (but exposes an externally-pure interface).

Comment: I think not, although it's nice knowing that exists.  I'd want the memoisation dumped when the implicit parameter `?necklaces` changes.  I found yairchu comment clarifying, basically implicit parameters might create additional opportunities, but only by explicitly making lambda expressions.  It feels like more should be possible, but okay.

Comment: Well, you'd just write `numerators :: V.Vector Necklace -> V.Vector Int`. Then, calls with the same parameter would produce the same result without recalculation. Admittedly, depending on how big your `Vector` is, the cost of looking it up in a tree structure might outweigh the cost of performing the `numerators` computation from scratch. GHC has the required facilities to build a memoisation library based on pointer identity of the input values, but I don't know if there's anything on Hackage for it.

Comment: By the way, implicit parameters are a very rare extension, and most people avoid them — I've only seen two pieces of code that actually use them, and they have nasty pitfalls, like adding a type signature to a definition changing its value.

Comment: Really?  How so?  I've found them quite elegant.  If I don't use implicit parameters, but do expose the optimal breaking of lambda expressions to GHC, then I must still assign a temporary value like `k = kittytoy necklaces` to invoke instead, and this value must get communicated amongst the various differeny functions calling `kittytoy`, that's what I'd like GHC to sort out.

Comment: Well, you can use the [`Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html) monad to encapsulate carrying around a common environment. If you really want to avoid the plumbing, you could also try Edward Kmett's [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package. But if implicit parameters work for you, that's great :)

Comment: I'm always nervous about monads for configuration because they come on the "wrong end" of the lambda expressions, i.e. `f :: Int -> Config -> Int` looks massively less efficient than `f :: Config -> Int -> Int`.  I'll check out reflection.

Comment: @ehird Why is `uglymemo` faster? Doesn't it have the same time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

There is another plausible approach arising from the fact that `type` now defined synonyms for type constrains, as noted in [Philip JF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683453/philip-jf)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599994/667457).

You could probably create a synonym for a type constraint that created implicit parameters for all the various derived values :

```
type Necklaces = (necklaces :: V.Vector Necklace,
                  denominator :: Int,
                  numerators :: V.Vector Int)

kittytoy :: (Necklaces) => Meow -> ...
```

You'd initially assign all the values like `?numerators` using a template Haskell construction of some form.  I'll play with it to see if it works.