# Type-level constraints in instances of type families

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

Is it possible to have type synonym families for parametrized data such as [Data.Param.FSVec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-data-0.1.5)?

Ideally, I would like this to compile:

```
class A e where
  type Arg e a
  f :: (Arg e a -> b) -> e a -> e b

instance A X where
  type Arg X a = Nat size => FSVec size a
  f = {- implementation -}
```

I have tried several workarounds, like wrapping `FSVec size a` in a newtype, or constraint synonyms, but it seems that I could not get anything reasonable right.

---

### Context + minimal working example

`A` is a class previously defined (for example) as such:

```
class OldA e where
  f :: (Maybe a -> b) -> [e (Maybe a)] -> [e b]
```

An example of type inheriting `OldA` is:

```
data Y a = Y a

instance Functor Y where
  fmap f (Y a) = Y (f a)

instance OldA Y where
  f = fmap . fmap
```

I want to extend this class to be able to express more general function arguments for `f`. Let's say we have a type `X` and an associated function `fIndependent`:

```
import qualified Data.Param.FSVec as V
import Data.TypeLevel hiding ((==))

data X a = X a deriving Show
fromX (X a) = a

fIndependent :: (Nat size) => (V.FSVec size (Maybe a) -> b) -> [X (Maybe a)] -> [X b]
fIndependent _ [] = []
fIndependent f xs = let x'  = (V.reallyUnsafeVector . take c . fmap fromX) xs
                        xs' = drop c xs
                        c   = V.length x'
                    in if c == length (V.fromVector x') then X (f x') : fIndependent f xs' else []
```

`fIndependent` is sane itself. Testing it with a function

```
test :: V.FSVec D2 x -> Int
test a = V.length a
```

will grant the result:

```
>>> fIndependent test $ map (X . Just) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[X 2, X 2, X 2, X 2]
```

Ok, now how to extend `OldA`? The most "natural" thing that came into my mind is to equip class `A` with a type synonym family `Arg e a` as below.

```
class NewA e where
  type Arg e a
  f :: (Arg e a -> b) -> [e (Maybe a)] -> [e b]
```

Converting all existing instances is easy:

```
instance NewA Y where
  type Arg Y a = Maybe a
  f = fmap . fmap  -- old implementation
```

To express `fIndependent` as f is the difficult part, since just adding

```
instance NewA X where
  type Arg X a = (Nat size) => FSVec size (Maybe a)  -- wrong!!!
  f = {- same as fIndependent -}
```

does not work. This is what I have trouble with.

---

### Try-outs

Most solutions I saw propose wrapping `FSVec` inside a `newtype`. Doing so does not help since the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype ArgV a = ArgV (forall rate.Nat rate => V.FSVec rate (Maybe a))

instance NewA X where
  type Arg X a = ArgV a
  g f xs = let x'  = (V.reallyUnsafeVector . take c . fmap fromX) xs
               xs' = drop c xs
               c   = V.length x'
           in if c == length (V.fromVector x') then X (f $ ArgV x') : g f xs' else []
```

the type inference system seems to lose the information about `size`:

```
Couldn't match type ‘s0’ with ‘rate’ …
      because type variable ‘rate’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context: Nat rate => V.FSVec rate (Maybe a)
    Expected type: V.FSVec rate (Maybe a)
      Actual type: V.FSVec s0 (Maybe a)
    Relevant bindings include
      x' :: V.FSVec s0 (Maybe a)
        (bound at ...)
    In the first argument of ‘Args’, namely ‘x'’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Args x'’
Compilation failed.
```

I would appreciate any lead or hint in this matter.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What problem are you trying to solve? What is `A` if there are "many existing instances of `A` imported from external libraries which work just fine"?

Comment: Sorry for not providing a context, but it's rather knotty. Here is a more elaborated [Git issue](https://github.com/forsyde/forsyde-atom/issues/5) providing also code snippets. In short: I am trying to include functions with a type signature like `f :: (Nat size) => (FSVec size a -> b) -> ...`  into a class where `f`'s signature is `f :: (Value a -> b) -> ...`. Needless to say, I can modify the code for the class, but it will take too much effort to modify the code for every instance, that is why I prefer type synonyms. I will shortly update the questions as well.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please include a complete minimal example, explanations of what the parts of the example are, and the resulting error from the compiler. That's the [minimum information for a question to be on topic and useful for other stack overflow users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Without that information a potential answerer can't tell if e.g. `X` is an attempt to "wrap `FSVec size a` in a newtype".

Comment: @Cirdec : it is done! I doubt that more details such as my attempts and errors could not shed more light into this matter. Moreover, I fear that it would fall into the "debugging help" category (as per the guide you sent), which I desperately wanted to avoid by formulating a general question for a general problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cirdec's answer explains one of the problems, but its solution given does not exactly answer the question posted. The question asks for an instance `X` for the class `A`, with a `FSVec` type synonym.

The overarching issue here that prevents defining `type Arg X = FSVec size a` (in any possible configuration) is that [type families are not injective](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Injectivity.2C_type_inference.2C_and_ambiguity). Knowing this and following Cirdec's reasoning, I can think of a workaround to achieve this goal: include a proxy "context" variable in `X`s type, to overcome the mentioned issue.

```
data X c a = X a

instance (Nat n) => A (X n) where
  type (X n) a = FSVec n a
  f = {- same as fIndependent -}
```

Of course, this is a quick fix that works for the minimal example (i.e. it answers the question posted), but might not scale well when composing multiple functions like `f` since there might appear type clashes between the inferred "contexts".

---

The best solution I can think of would be to add a [constraint synonym](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html) (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599994/2421116)) for each instance, like:

```
import qualified Data.Param.FSVec
import Data.TypeLevel
import GHC.Exts  -- for Constraint kind

class A e where
  type Arg e context a
  type Ctx e context :: Constraint
  f :: (Ctx e context) => (Arg e context a -> b) -> [e (Maybe a)] -> [e b]

instance A Y where
  type Arg Y c a = Maybe a
  type Ctx Y c = ()
  f = {- same as before -}

instance A X where
  type Arg X size a = V.FSVec size (Maybe a)
  type Ctx X size = Nat rate
  f = {- same as fIndependent -}
```

But then we would have to deal with the ambiguous types resulted due to the infamous non-injectivity of type families (e.g. `Could not deduce: Arg e context0 a ~ Arg e context a`). In this case proving injectivity would have to be done manually using the [TypeFamilyDependencies](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/InjectiveTypeFamilies) extension (based on [injective type families](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/injective-type-families-acm.pdf)) available in GHC 8.0, and define `Arg` as:

```
type family Arg (e :: * -> *) context = (r :: * -> *) | r -> context
```

Of course, this is not possible if the design of the type family is not injective (which is my case), but it is the cleanest solution so far. It is definitely recommended if one can design her type family using the guidelines in the [provided paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/injective-type-families-acm.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure entirely what you're trying to do, but it seems to me that all you really need is to write the function `Nat n => Y a -> Y (FSVec n a)` for whichever `Y`s support this regrouping. Then the class `OldA` doesn't change at all, and there's an easy place to inject what the natural number `n` is.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using a class `Nat :: k -> Constraint` and a data type `FSVec :: k -> * -> *`. The data type is constrained with the old [`DatatypeContexts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#datatype-contexts) extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

class Nat n

data Nat n => FSVec n a = FSVec -- ...
```

You have an existing class `A :: (* -> *) -> Constraint` which you'd like to write an `FSVec` instance for.

```
class A e where
  --- ...
  f :: ( {- ... -} b) -> e a -> e b
```

But `FSVec` can never have an `A` instance, because it's a kind mismatch. The class `A` requires a type argument with the kind `* -> *` but `FSVec` has the kind `k -> * -> *`. You've already run into a problem, and aren't even using the type family yet. If you try to do this (hand waving away what the type family argument is for now)

```
data X = X

instance A (FSVec) where
  type Arg FSVec a = X
  f = undefined
```

You get a compiler error.

```
    Expecting one more argument to `FSVec'
    The first argument of `A' should have kind `* -> *',
      but `FSVec' has kind `* -> * -> *'
    In the instance declaration for `A (FSVec)'
```

Everything before here, including the compiler error, is useful information for communicating the problem you are having and is useful in asking for help.

---

Fortunately it's a really easy problem to fix. If you pick some natural number `n`, then `FSVec n` has the kind `* -> *`, which matches the kind of the type argument to `A`. You can start writing an `instance A (FSVec n)`

```
instance A (FSVec n) where
  f = -- ...
```

When you reintroduce the complete class definition with type families

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class A e where
  type Arg e a
  f :: (Arg e a -> b) -> e a -> e b
```

The solution is still to write an `A` instance for `FSVec n` instead of for `FSVec`. Now that `n` has moved into the `instance` declaration, there's an obvious place to capture the needed `Nat n` context.

```
instance Nat n => A (FSVec n) where
  type Arg (FSVec n) a = FSVec n a
  f = undefined -- ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not know the trick with `f = undefined`. On the other hand I fail to make the connection how can making `FSVec n` an instance of `A` help me with implementing the instance of `X` where the function argument is `FSVec n`. Could you please elaborate or point me to some documentation/examples since it seems I lack important background knowledge.

Comment: @GeorgeUngureanu How are you going to determine `size` from `X`? How will the compiler? Is there some reason that the existence of a `Nat size` dictionary is all that needs to be known about the type `size`?

Comment: I understand now that this is almost the answer I need. But instead of making `FSVec` an instance of `A`, in order to stick to the question `X` (which is the type I need to instantiate) should be defined as to contain a `Nat` context (e.g. `X n a = X a`). I will edit the answer and mark it as accepted. Thanks again!